# Ember - Extending {{component}} helper

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What I want to do is to pass a string to [`{{component}}`](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component) helper, but I want more control over what string it gets passed in at runtime.

e.g.

```
// getComponentToRender will get the current UI theme in the app, 
// determine whether it's running on the mobile mode, then fetches the 
// appropriate name of a component to render based on the type of the
// component. Just an example.
{{component getComponentToRender(ComponentType.Button)}}
```

I investigated this, it turns out this isn't possible (Otherwise, please correct me). Of course, there's [computed](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/object-model/computed-properties/) property, but it doesn't take an argument.

Next, I looked into extending the helper. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083417/calling-a-helper-from-another-helper) stackoverflow question shows you can extend one, but I couldn't locate where the `component` helper is located in Ember. There doesn't seem to be any questions/documentation regarding extending existing helpers, either. This is what I would do with this approach.

```
// I can't find where the {{component}} helper is located.
import Component from './???'

export default Component.extend({
     compute(componentType, hash) {
         let componentName = getComponentToRender(componentType);
         this._super(componentName, hash)
     }
})
```

What did I miss? It'd be great if someone can put me into the right direction.

Comment: Maybe checkout [flexi](https://flexi.readme.io/docs)

Comment: Flexi is a UI framework. My question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Flexi is solving what you want: how to have multiple layouts for the same component. So maybe it could help you to check how they solved that. Just wanted to point you there, sorry. I thought it would be interesting for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only way of calling a function from a template is writing an helper. Actually your reference StackOverflow question is also mentioning about helpers. [Writing an helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/templates/writing-helpers/) will solve your problem.

You don't need to extend the `component` helper. You need to compose it. As following:

```
{{component (getComponentToRender ComponentType.Button)}}
```

Here is the [working twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1ec38b7c83e50f90a58ebcca5d11e1a4?openFiles=helpers.my-helper.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't tried it as Im out, but Ill have a look. To answer your question, I could have several brandings of the same app for different purposes. So in Product X, it could be red, but Product Y could be blue. They are different products, but it is mostly using the same code. Well, it was just an example. I'm not really doing that atm.

Comment: I tried out your answer, but I don't think it works. Nothing is getting rendered. Please see it on this twiddle. https://ember-twiddle.com/3a6dfa56a59a4f81e5883d88c59d3459?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs

Comment: You are absolutely right. I had fixed my mind that params was not an array (even thought it has an 's'!). It works as expected now.